# Run multiple queries for multiple users in SQL Server using Node.js

Tags: node.js, sql-server, loops, large-data, connection-timeout

I have a large number of user records. I'll explain what I want and what I've done.

First I'm fetching active users records from the database and then in for loop I'm checking their details from another table, then calling a third party API and update the user database for every users.

Once the loop is completed, I'm starting the process again from the beginning, this will continue infinitely. This is what I've done.

The problem is: if I have 1000 active users, it is working fine, but if I have more users, the execution time is increasing second by second; at last I'm getting execution timeout error from the database.

Even with 1000 users also it's working for 10-12 hours only after that the same error came. I want to check another table and then call a RESTAPI and then update a table for many users at the same time.

How can I achieve this in Node.js? I'm using Node.js and SQL Server. Please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance

Comment: can you please put your sample code. It will give more clarity

Comment: For checking purpose you can try joins  with LIMIT ? ,as you are already calling the apis ,and for other part calling third api ,you can try some queue and you just need to push the data in queue and the subscriber with event driven code can call the api for you ,the processing might take bit more time not much but the process would be smooth and reliable

Comment: There is nowhere near enough information to speculate, if I understand correct you are saying the same operation is taking longer, the longer the system has been running? The normal cause of that is failure to free up resources. But really no way to tell based on the information provided.